# Tomcat server in Eclipse errors on web.xml

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jsf, tomcat

I'm new to JSP/JSF & Richfaces & Tomcat.

I currently have a project checkout out locally and have tomcat configured in my eclipse installation to run my project.

Now the following message seems to be randomly occurring when I start tomcat from eclipse:

"cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'head' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '($|*|\p{L})(\p{L}|\p{Nd}|*|$)*' for type 'null'."

I originally thought it was when I was making changes to my web.xml file.
Mainly because when I would go back and undo a change I made, the server would start up successfully.

But sometimes it seems that this error will be thrown, I will make no changes, come back 10 minutes later and start the server and it works fine!

I should also add that immediately after that error message I describe the following also is displayed:

```
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
20-Jan-2011 16:33:56 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/myApp] startup failed due to previous errors
20-Jan-2011 16:33:56 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myApp] appears to have started a thread named [pool-2-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
20-Jan-2011 16:33:56 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that your app can be deployed on a tomcat instance without this problem then it should be an issue with the way tomcat has been setup from eclipse. Also is tomcat shutting down without a problem? I would suggest create a new tomcat server (quickly by right clicking on the `servers` panel > `New` > `Server`) and redeploy there in order to eliminate the one-off case.

Comment: When this error pops up, I will try to stop it and its take a good 30 seconds before telling me its not responding and would I like to kill it. I'll try creating a new tomcat server and see if the problems continues to happen.

Comment: If tomcat halts there, if you want to kill it instantly go in the Debug view and select one of the first threads (Catalina should be in the name) and click the stop button.